# Cell border not connecting when expanding height of row

Tags: tables

I've got this code but as you can see only the left cell borders are connecting with the top `\hline`
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 

\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]

\begin{tabular}{|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|C{3cm}|}
\hline
\\[-1em]
Mass (g) & Position (cm) & $ \mathbf{ \frac{Mass}{Position}\left( \frac{g}{cm} \right) }$ \\[2pt] \hline 
 &  & \\ \hline
 &  & \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: remove `\\[-1em]`

Comment: I need to have space above and below the first row; that is the purpose of `\\[-1em]` and `\\[2pt]`

Comment: it is completely wrong syntax, by adjusting the length you may get something that looks ok but if you use `\\ ` after  \hline then any result is accidental error correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- By using `tabularray` package you will avoid your problem:

[image]

- I suspect that table body rows are numbers.
- Unfortunately it is not known how many digits they have and if they are decimal numbers.
- if above is know, than you can use `S` columns type defined in `siunitx` package, for example:

```
Q[c, wd=30mm, 
  si={table-format=<number of integers>:<number of decimals>}]
```

- Using above definition of columns you need for text in the first row add `row{1} = {guard}` option to `tblr` specifications.
- So far MWE below consider your column definition.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath, siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \sisetup{per-mode = fraction}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={ *{4}{Q[c, wd=30mm]} },
             row{1} = {rowsep=5pt}
             }
Mass (g)    & Position (cm) & $\dfrac{\text{Mass}}{\text{Position}} 
                               \displaystyle\left(\si{\gram\per\centi\metre}\right)$    \\
            &               &                                               \\
            &               &                                               \\         
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fantastic, time to learn another package!